# Java connection to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection

First some Infos:
- I use Android Studio to make an App
- the mySQL Database is running via XAMPP

I am trying to connect to my local mysql Database with the following Source Code:

```
FConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.2:3306/[DatabaseName]", "[Username]", "[Password]");
```

When I run this i get the Error Message:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
>   The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

I tried to make a Telnet from my PC and all I get is:

> 5.5.5-10.1.25-MariaDB4Sam~VoM?áp`p2DC`=NO#]mysql_native_password 
>   Lost Connection to Host

I hope that is enough Info and you guys can help me.

Comment: possible dublicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai

Comment: Already read that Post, but didn't worded for me

Comment: Don't connect directly to a database from Android. Use a (rest) service as an intermediate.

Comment: Sorry I am new to Java. Didn't knew that I have to make a new Thread.